# storing image information using class Image

Tags: java, awt

> Class Image is an abstract class—as a result, programs cannot instantiate class Image to create objects. To achieve platform independence, the Java implementation on each platform provides its own subclass of Image to store image information.

The text is about class `java.awt.Image`.

I don't understand the second part, namely:-

> ... provides its own subclass of Image to store image information.

Technically, how does that happen?

Comment: Nowadays you would rather use BufferedImage that is platform-independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image` instances are typically created through methods such as [`Toolkit.createImage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage%28byte%5b%5d%29). In this case, the actual instantiation of the `Image` object is delegated to the `Toolkit` class, which is platform-dependent.

Note that while you cannot directly instantiate class `Image`, you can instantiate [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), which is a concrete `Image` subclass.

Comment: Right. This means that the implementation must also provide a subclass of Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The concrete subclass of `Image` might, in some cases, be a class which isn't part of the public API of the JDK. (In other cases, you might find that you're getting a `BufferedImage`, which is much nicer in the event that you intend to do something with the image you get.)

Try `System.out.println(img.getClass().getName());` just to see what you're getting.